# want to put in in the style tags and Tell the h1 font size to be 50 pixels if the screen is narrower than 500px

Tags: html, css, media

I am learning how to use the @media tage. I want to put in in the style tags and Tell the h1 font size to be 50 pixels if the screen is narrower than 500px

What is the syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {font-size: 50px}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For specific max-width of 500px you will write like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h1 {
       font-size: 50px
       }
}
```

If you want to specify the min and max height, depending on your needs. It is useful when you have to break multiple times. So if your max width is 500px but you want to specify font-size only for the range of 500-300px, you will write like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 300px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 50px; 
      }
}
```